# ArrayPool create method in C#

Tags: c#, buffer, compiler-optimization

I was using with ArrayPool in C#.
I wanted to create my own pool with max no of arrays 5 and max size of array 1050000.
I used this ArrayPool.Create() method.
I am not able to understand one thing - i am trying to rent from the pool 10 times in the snippet below ,although i specified max arrays to be 5 , then why is it not showing any error.
Also, i specified max length to be 1050000.Then how am i able to rent a 4200000 array without any error ?

```
        byte[] buffer;
        ArrayPool<byte> pool = ArrayPool<byte>.Create(1050000, 5);

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            buffer = pool.Rent(4200000);
        }
```

Comment: You specify a minimum size for rent, as they are being reused , if you want a larger size, you need to rent the minimum size you need. Also what is the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: Hey , i edited my question and added that

Comment: I've rolled back your edit. It is an entirely separate and should be asked as a new question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The options passed to `ArrayPool.Create` don't imply you cannot recieve an array larger than those limits. Instead they are used to control the bucketing algorithm of the `ConfigurableArrayPool`. The second argument is the maximum number of slots in a bucket and the first is the maximum size of any array. This value is capped by an [internal constant](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/4f9ae42d861fcb4be2fcd5d3d55d5f227d30e723/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Buffers/ConfigurableArrayPool.cs#L139) of `1,048,576` which is already *smaller* than your `1,050,000`.

When you `Rent` from the array pool, the algorithm will attempt to locate an array in one of the buckets/slots. The number of these buckets (and their internal slots) are what become limited by the values you passed in. If the pool doesn't have an array of the *minimum* size requested either because all slots are in use or because the requested size is greater than the maximum, it will instead **allocate** a new one (without pooling it) and return that.

In short, when you request an array larger than the (capped) size you passed in to the `Create` method you will incur an allocation and recieve an array that does not participate in the pool. Calling `Return` with this array will not place it back into the pool; instead [it will be "dropped"](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/4f9ae42d861fcb4be2fcd5d3d55d5f227d30e723/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Buffers/ConfigurableArrayPool.cs#L139).

Keep in mind however that these rules only apply to the built-in array pool. You (or someone else) could write an implementation that caps the size of the returned array or even throws -- though I'd argue that those *might* not be considered well-behaved (at least without supporting doc).

**Update** based on your comments:

While true there is not a parameter that corresponds directly to the number of buckets, there is *indirectly*. The number of buckets is calculated using the maximum array size you pass in. The [max buckets is determined](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/4f9ae42d861fcb4be2fcd5d3d55d5f227d30e723/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Buffers/ConfigurableArrayPool.cs#L48) based on  powers of 2 and [some other logic](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/4f9ae42d861fcb4be2fcd5d3d55d5f227d30e723/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Buffers/Utilities.cs#L18).

Comment: Thanks a lot . Can u pls look at the edit i made which describes what i am trying to resolve .

Comment: That's a whole different question and you should roll back your edit and post a new one. But I can tell you right away (and I suspected this just from your description) that you are ignoring the return result of `Stream.Read` and assuming that it fills your entire buffer. It can return anywhere from 1 to the size of the buffer and is likely capped at a realistic value. You need to handle the cases where the number of bytes read is less (which will likely be always given your buffer size)

Comment: We have no control over the number of buckets which will be created but just over the number of arrays per bucket ,right?

Comment: Also how does having different buckets help us ?

Comment: The number of buckets is determined by the max array size. They take log2 and perform some other calculations to determine. How buckets help I can't say. But some very smart people designed it to be efficient otherwise having a pool wouldn't make sense. If you want to know for sure you may want to ask a question on the dotnet github (or post a new question here)

Comment: I don't know where you got the internal constant of 1,048,576, but the source code you linked to actually has a maximum size constant of 1,048,576 * 1024 (2^30).

Answer (score 1):

[Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.buffers.arraypool-1.rent?view=netcore-3.1) has no exceptions defined for the `Rent` method (though there is at least one which can be thrown - `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` for negative array sizes).

Looking at the source [code](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/ArrayPool.cs,98e8c283b6b5930d) for the `Create` method - it returns [`ConfigurableArrayPool`](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/ConfigurableArrayPool.cs,a837acd82174ff14). It's `Rent` method will try to find an array matching for the request and if there is no suitable one it will just allocate a new one:

```
// The request was for a size too large for the pool.  Allocate an array of exactly the requested length.
// When it's returned to the pool, we'll simply throw it away.
buffer = new T[minimumLength];
```

So both parameters (`maxArrayLength` and `maxArraysPerBucket`) are used just to control what `ArrayPool` will actually store and reuse, not how much can be allocated (and it makes sense, usually you don't want your application to fail while allocating memory if there is enough of memory available to it). Everything else will be in the control of `GC`, so `ArrayPool` will not end up storing a lot of noncollectable memory.

Comment: Thanks a lot . Can u pls look at the edit i made which describes what i am trying to resolve

Comment: We have no control over the number of buckets which will be created but just over the number of arrays per bucket ,right?

Comment: Also how does having different buckets help us ?